# Why does 'manpath' work and 'echo $MANPATH' does not?

Tags: configuration, environment-variables, man

I was just wondering why `echo $MANPATH` does not work (on my system (Debian Jessie x86_64 GNU/Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64)). The `manpath` command alone works well:

```
user@host:~$ manpath
/usr/local/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man
```

/etc/manpath.config - exists and contains uncommented lines, according to the ones listed by `manpath`.

The manpath man page says:

> If $MANPATH is set, manpath will simply display its contents ...

So, why does `manpath` work and `echo $MANPATH` doesn't?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From my `man manpath` (Ubuntu 16.10 - as you didn't mention your system details):

> If $MANPATH is set, manpath displays its value rather than determining
>   it on the fly.

So `$MANPATH` is more of an override to the otherwise default configuration held by `/etc/manpath.config`.

Note also:

> DESCRIPTION
>
> If $MANPATH is set, manpath will simply display its contents and issue a warning.  If not, manpath will determine a suitable manual page hierarchy search path and display the results.

Answer (score 2):

Cause that is all about the variable `$MANPATH` existence: To be overwritten if a customized manpath is needed.

Quoting Debian Lenny manpages:

> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> If  `$MANPATH`  is  set,  manpath will simply display its contents
>   and issue a warning.  If not, manpath will determine a suitable 
>   manual  page hierarchy search path and display the results.
>
> The  colon-delimited  path  is  determined using information gained
>   from the man-db configuration file - (`/etc/manpath.config`) and  the 
>   user’s  environment.

When the manual page say "If `$MANPATH` is set," the meaning is "if this variable is set by the user or script..." or "if this variable is empty, use the defaults located at `manpath.config`".

Take a time and crawl through the `/etc/manpath.config` file to learn how all manpages path are structured.

**Related Stuff:**

Some links about manipulating `$MANPATH` or creating custom man pages path.

- [Easy way to restore your MANPATH](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/17979/easy-way-to-restore-your-manpath)
- [How can I add man page entries for my own power tools?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6891/how-can-i-add-man-page-entries-for-my-own-power-tools/)
- [Debian lists - Re: How command "manpath" works?](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2003/08/msg00922.html)
- [FreeBSD manpath(1) manpages](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=manpath&apropos=0&sektion=1&manpath=FreeBSD%2011.0-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&arch=default&format=html) - This manpage is interesting for learning purposes cause it express more clearly what are the implications of having `$MANPATH` set.